# How do I install COM port component on Delphi 2009 CodeGear?

Tags: delphi, serial-port

I'm using *CodeGear Delphi 2009* and tried to install a couple of *COM port* components, but that failed. Could you tell me where I could get a good, free *COM port* component and how do I install it to IDE?(e.g. which ancestor shall I specify?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have been using several years.

[**Serial version 4.4**](http://toolbox.reworld.eu/projekte/serial/right.htm)

Unfortunately, the download link is no longer available. You have to search the Internet.

The Unit Serial contains a collection of components associated with the serial interface of the PC.
The core components are the two TSerial and TSerPort.
Both are based on the Windows API, but offer much more comfortable and also flexible ways to access this interface.
In 1998, Version 2.0 was first released in the computer magazine Toolbox.
In subsequent years, the collection has components continuously developed and improved. The level of development, is now equivalent to commercial solutions. Particularly therefore has "TSerial" become widespread in industrial applications.

**TComPort**

Delphi/C++ Builder serial communications components.
It is generally easy to use for basic Serial Communications purposes. Alternative to the TurboPower ASYNCPro.

[TComPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe synapse has support for serial ports also:

http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download